# Linux 2 GB RAM AWS EC2 Debian ARM64 instance showing incorrect total memory

Tags: debian, aws, amazon-ec2, arm64

I have provisioned a 2 GB RAM AWS EC2 instance and using a ARM64 Debian 10 AMI. When I do `top` and `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo`. I get total memory of 1898 instead of 2048 MB. Even if the reserved memory of Debian is taken into consideration a differential of 150MB seemed a little too high. Is it a EC2 instance issue or something to do with my AMI?

Provisioned: 2 GB = 2048 MB;
As per top : 1,898 MB;
As per free -m : 1898MB;
As per freekbytes: 45056KB = 44MB;

Debian AMI instance - ami-059a9b1093495222c (64-bit x86) / ami-03b05547d5c0bbfe4 (64-bit Arm)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: we can't read photos of your laptop screen with a reflection taking at an angle with a camera. Please use the screenshot functionality of your operating system. Also, if the information you want to convey is actually just text, copy and paste the text, use code formatting if necessary.

Comment: All of that is text, please [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, copy/paste the text into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. These images are useless, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 4):

A difference of 150MiB isn’t surprising. The total memory shown by `free`, `/proc/meminfo`, `top` etc. is the maximum amount of memory accessible to programs; it doesn’t count memory used by the kernel binary or memory reserved by the system firmware.

The kernel’s logs should include a `Memory:` line which gives details of the reserved memory. You can look for it with

```
sudo dmesg | grep Memory:
```

Comment: Which is supposed to be holding this firmware reserve in case of cloud providers like AWS? Second, is such a case similar in other cloud providers like GCP and Azure as well?

Comment: Second, can I also change the firmware reserved memory manually? I am unaware

Comment: Firmware shouldn’t be a factor on a cloud platform. I suspect this is all kernel-reserved memory.

Comment: Right. Even I thought so. freekbytes should give the kernel reserved memory? Or do I write a different command. In case of grep memory, it did show me 1849/ 2062 mb of memory. What may be going wrong here and how can I rectify this? Want to assign the least memory allocation possible

Comment: There’s nothing wrong here, the kernel needs memory to function. You could try building a smaller kernel but it’s probably not worth the effort; most well-built AMIs have a small kernel already.